# Accept more than one answer

Tags: discussion

In reference of my [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31347/circular-plot-and-circular-histogram) question, the question is answered by **David Carraher** and **Mr.Wizard** both answers are acceptable for me. But I know we can accept only one answer at a time. I am confused what to do? I wish I accept both the answers, Can I do this?

Comment: You might want to look at this [related question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/920/3066).

Comment: No, you cannot Accept two answers.  See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/158428) old Q&A on the Stack Overflow Meta site for some background.

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate of the one m_goldberg linked.  If you find the answers there unsatisfying let me know why.